# Is it a good idea to store pictures / images in SQLite DB from the App?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, sqlite

Some discussions in Stackoverflow say that storing the picture in DB is a bad idea (a because overtime, the number of images get large & may lead to app crash). So, either

a. the image can be stored in the iPhone itself & only its location can be stored in the DB
       Potential Issue: The image might get removed (outside of the app) & the app might not be able to load them the next time

b. the image can be shrunk to a small size (say, 100*100 pixels) and stored in the DB 
       Potential Issue: will size be an issue if the image is shrunk to just 100x100pixels?

c. Doing both (a) & (b). So, small versions of the images will be stored in the DB and then, retrieved & displayed in the App, whereas, if the user chooses to see the original version of the image (whose probability is low), then that'll be fetched from the local directory & shown.

Your suggestions please? In my opinion, (c) seems a good option to go in for, in case (a) has the potential issue mentioned.

Comment: +1 Looking for same, I am storing images with core data is it good ? If i use directory to save images then apple will reject the app due to size of directory ?

Comment: this is not place to provide suggestion. Please share what you have done, or what you are trying !!!

Comment: +1 from me, too. Though iPhone Fun is partially right (this is not a place for debates like a forum would be) but Jean asked a completly legite question in search for good practice. @Jean: iPhone stores both, images & thumbnails, as files. So maybe (i really don't know) it would be best to follow their example. In db you could only store the filenames (if you think it's neccessery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on where the images are coming from. Are they being downloaded from the Internet (or imported from the user's library / camera) after the user installs the app, or are they bundled with the app from the App Store?

If the images are being downloaded / imported, the best solution is to store images in the filesystem following the recommendations in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html

Basically, if the images cannot be replaced or recreated, store them in the `<Application_Home>/Documents` directory and do not set the `Do Not Backup` attribute. These items will be backed up to iCloud, and this data does persist for at least some amount of time even if the app is deleted from the device. (Remember that your users do not have unlimited iCloud space. Be responsible.)

-However-

If the images are bundled with the app, the best solution is to import them directly into your Xcode project and reference them from there. This way you know they are always available even if the user deletes and reinstalls the app.

I would definitely stay away from storing image data in the databased whenever possible. There are simply better, more efficient ways in most any scenario.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, Josh. And thanks to all for your comments and suggestions. Very helpful. I should have mentioned: in the app, the user is allowed to either shoot a new pic or choose one from their existing photo library. So, maybe, storing locally will be a good idea? And is it to be stored in <Application_Home>/Documents dir or in Library/Caches (some discussions in this forum said that it's a good idea to store in Library/Caches) directory? Please suggest.

Comment: The major difference between Caches and Documents is that Documents data is safe from any kind of system purge (low memory situations) and it's also backed up.

Comment: Cache is for data that can be recreated by your app without your user knowing anything ever happened. In this case, you'll need to use the Documents directory or your user may find his photos unexpectedly deleted and your app won't even know why.

Comment: Thanks so much, Josh! That was truly helpful & explanatory! Thank you :)